# Is it possible to render to a octahedron texture directly?

Tags: rendering, projections

I am considering using octahedron textures for environment mapping, opposed to sphere or cube mapping due to their low memory footprint and the quality they result in.

Is there a possibility to render to such an octahedron texture directly (i.e. 3D -> Octahedron)?
[image]
Rendering to a cubemap and then to the octahedron is fairly straight forward since I can use the Octahedron Texture Coordinates to retrieve the cubemap direction for sampling.
But I would like to skip the intermediate cubemap. The octahedron textures are supposed to be generated at load time behind a loading screen.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can do.... **Step 1:** create a framebuffer where your texture array is attached to (one layer for each triangle in your image). **Step 2:** create a shader program with geometry shader where the geometry shader duplicates the rendered geometry 8 times and bring these to the 8 layers of your texture. Also apply the rotation matrix of the response triangle. **Step 3:** add clipping planes for each layer. Here you need 3 clipping planes for each of the 8 triangles (at least 1 clipping plane for the diagonal edge).

Comment: Again not sure if this works... Trying to do it with viewport array... each viewport will be set to the reagion of a triangle in your final image... I never used viewport arrays before so I'm not sure if this works out

Comment: have in mind, that geometry shaders will slow down the rendering process... So not sure if you realy want to do so